# CSS: How to align buttons and text horizontally

Tags: html, css

I have the following month selector:

[image]

It has a left and a right button with the text of the current month inbetween.
As you can see it doesn't look ok.

HTML:

```
<div id="seletor">
        <a class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w" href="#" id="subtrair">subtrair</a>
            <div id="mescorrente"></div>
        <a class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e" href="#" id="somar">somar</a>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#subtrair, #mescorrente, #somar {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#subtrair, #somar {
    margin-top:2px;
}
#mescorrente {
    font-size:20px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding:0 6px; /* optional padding.. */
    margin-bottom:10px;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
```

I tried all sorts of options in the display settings, like `display:table` and `display:inline` but it did not work.

In Chrome Dev Tools, if I uncheck and check again `display:inline-block;` it works!

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Check out the `:before` and `:after` selectors for css.

Comment: I've got .ui-helper-clearfix:before, .ui-helper-clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CSS for `#mescorrente`.

```css
#mescorrente {
  min-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please post in English.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options that I see here. Either you can create multiple div elements and display them inline, or you could use

```
<span>
```

element, as it is intended to display elements inline natively.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp

I would recommend using the span element, as I've had good success using this method, so long as you want them truly inline and not staggered/relatively  aligned via script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

`<a class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e" href="#" id="somar" style="float:right;">somar</a>`

or

```
#somar {
margin-top:2px;
float:right;
```

}

but as long as you use px in your parameters, if the above ways does not help, you can set the distance form the left side like this:

```
#somar {
margin-top:2px;
left: 150px;
```

}

Comment: The second proposal worked ok with a specified width of #seletor. But, because the length of the words varies, so the position of the right button...

Answer (score 0):

Just a slightly different approach - floating the three components left inside the div, then positioning the div - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCRyG/).

Did you want to do anything more with it?

CSS

```
#seletor {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
#subtrair, #mescorrente, #somar {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#subtrair, #somar {
    margin-top:2px;
}
#mescorrente {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:0 6px; /* optional padding.. */
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
```